# Prevent nested label link from following, but change checkbox state

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, click, label

I have an issue where I have the following markup:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="foo" />
<label for="foo">
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
        Checkbox text
    </a>
</label>
```

The label has a nested anchor in case the user doesn't have javascript enabled, and in which case they will follow the link when clicking the label.

I have the following javascript/jQuery to prevent the link click and to show an alert when the  checkbox state has changed:

```
$(function(){
    $("label a").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault(); 
    });
    $("#foo").change(function(){
       alert("checkbox changed"); 
    });
});
```

[**-- See Example --**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hc32s/2/)

However when clicking the label the checkbox checked state isn't changed.

I'm aware I could *hack* the code and try and emulate the native browser functionality by adding code to set the checked status, however I would prefer to use the native functionality than emulate it.

How can I get the checkbox to change state without following the link, and without setting the checked state using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bit confused here `and without setting the checked state using javascript?`...
but i think you are talking about `trigger()`...

```
$("label a").click(function(e){
    var $foo = $("#foo");
    $foo.attr("checked", !$foo.attr("checked"));
    $foo.trigger('change');
   return false;
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/Hc32s/3/)

Comment: I didn't think of using `trigger`, thanks! I've updated your answer to change the checked state before triggering. This isn't the perfect solution I was after, but I think this is the best you can get with nested link in labels.